# picture/video link opening on top of page

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm VERY new to html coding (5/6 weeks) and I'm having a problem getting my head around something. I'd like to be able to click on an image and instead of opening a new page have it's image or embedded video load inside a floating page (I'm sure there is a correct name for this) that loads on top of the existing page.

I've found several examples of this (one of which is linked below) but I'm still baffled. Is it just code from the main.css I need or do I require javascript etc. aswell. I've tried copYing over several bits of css code but to no success. It seems to always open a new page and not a floating page like in the example I've included below.

example: https://html5up.net/parallelism

when you click an image in the above site it opens/pops up a floating box (again sorry for not knowing what it is called) in the way I'd love to understand. I really want to use this technique as my site will be image and video heavy. I feel this approach will be a far a more professional way to display my information and images.

If anyone can help I'd love to learn exactly what I need to do to implement this. It might only be 5/6 weeks but I feel I've learned quite a bit. I want to keep upskilling to the point that I can maintain this website entirely by myself.

Thanks to everyone in advance,

Al.

Comment: The name of the popup you're looking for is `modal`. There's plenty of frameworks that can handle creation of those for you quite easily (such as Bootstrap), though all approaches will require JavaScript. If you don't want to import a heavy framework, [*Micromodal*](https://micromodal.now.sh/) works well for me. Unfortuantely, however, your question outside of asking the name of the popup is a bit too broad, which makes it '[**off-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)' for StackOverflow. For further information, please take the [*tour of the site*](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp  try this out

Comment: Hey all. I adapted this to suit my needs. Thanks for everyone's help

Answer (score 0):

Here's instructions for a framework-based modal - [Getbootstrap Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/)

Below is a non-framework modal -

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  background: url(http://subtlepatterns.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/grid.png) repeat #fefefe;
}
.button {
  margin: 20px auto;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #666;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  top: 50px;
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
.button:hover {
  color: #333;
  background: #eeffff;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
.modalbg {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  z-index: 99999;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  transition: all 2s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -transition-delay: 0.2s;
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.modalbg .dialog {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  top: -1000px;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
}
.modalbg .dialog .ie7 {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#000', Direction=135, Strength=3);
}
.modalbg:target {
  display: block;
  pointer-events: auto;
  background: rgba(4, 10, 30, 0.8);
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
.modalbg:target .dialog {
  top: -20px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.4s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.4s;
  -transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
.close {
  background: #606061;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.close:hover {
  background: #00d9ff;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
.fineprint {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #646;
}
a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="#openModal">Open Me!</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalbg">
  <div class="dialog">
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">x</a>
   <h2>You did it!</h2>
  <p>Below is a picture.</p>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150?random" style="margin: 0 auto; display: block;">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please be sure to mark the answer correct if it is a solution for you.